# How to telnet to an IP address on a specific port?

Tags: port, telnet

Can anyone tell me how to telnet to an address using a specific port?

I've tried the following:

```
telnet 10.1.1.55
```

I suppose a route just hasn't been set up between the two hosts?

What I am trying to do is this. We have a medical device – a ventilator. it is connected to the network via a converter box called ECOV-110 on this ip address. This device, displays messages when it gives oxygen and other things it does for the patient. We would like to capture these messages, and update the Patients record in the database.

So I am trying to `telnet` to the Ecov 110 and see if there is any data there to capture.

Comment: ah so ecov 110 product - the 110 means it is operating on the port 110?

Comment: Not sure what OS you are trying to do this from, but try typing "telnet /?", should give you the syntax and sturcture for the command as well as arguments you can add to it. Like others have said I think you just need to add a space and the port number after the IP, but this will give you more detailed informaiton on the telenet command.

Comment: Note that the machine at that IP needs to be running a telnet "daemon" or server.  It's not an automatic given that you can connect to any machine via Telnet.  Check the documentation to your device to ensure it responds to Telnet.

Answer (score 185):

The port number is the second parameter to telnet

```
telnet 10.1.55.55 110
```

to telnet to port 110.

Comment: In addition, the default port for telnet is 23. Disclaimer: your device maybe different, so I'd check the manual!

Answer (score 20):

On a normal Unix machine the port is just the second argument on the command line.  If you wanted to telnet to your device on port 12345 you'd use:

```
telnet 10.1.1.55 12345
```

You have to be able to establish a connection to the remote host and know which port number you want to talk to, though.

Comment: This also works with the windows telnet client.

Answer (score 3):

A simple Web search for ecov-110 turned up the user manual here - I presume this is the unit anyway:

http://www.tysso.com/docs/ecov110usersmanual.pdf

The manual covers use of a tool to identify the device on the network and how to interface with it. Since this device is being used in a medical setting I'd speak to the suppliers before trying any DIY interfacing just in case there are any technical or legal reasons why you shoould not be doing such.

Answer (score 0):

Just get a telnet client like PuTTy. It will ask you for the Host Address (the IP address of the box you want to access).

Answer (score 0):

> ah so ecov 110 product - the 110 means it is operating on the port 110? – Booksman

No, 110 is simply the model number of the product. You can choose a specific port yourself. A look through the [manual](http://www.digielite.com.au/ecov110.pdf) does not really specify a default port, but there are occurrences of port 4000 and port 5001, but it looks like 4000 is the normal one. Therefore, try using the following command:

```
telnet 10.1.1.55 4000
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is partially the port, but according to the user manual at www.saelig.com/supplier/fametech/ecov110usersmanual.pdf , you don't telnet to it; rather you download a special application.